# Unable to add object to generic list using wildcard

Tags: java, generics

Why can't I add any object here , I was hoping I would be allowed to add any kind of object in such a list.

```
List<?> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
l.add(new Object());
l.add(new String("hello"));
```

Comment: The ? stands for some unknown type. Any parameter we assign would have to be a subtype of this unknown type. Since we don't know what type that is, we cannot pass anything in. So as per rule Object should be a subtype of ? and compiler doesn't know what this unknown type(?) is. The sole exception is null, which is a member of every type.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
    List<Object> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(new Object());
    l.add(new String("hello"));
```